# How to multiply from 12 all the way to 1 with a 'for' function with R language

Tags: r, for-loop

My question is related to calculate the multiplies of 12 (factorials) in a for loop:

I spent a lot of time on this but can`t solve it!

It is important to use a **function with a 'for' loop**!

So far: I had tried doing

```
for(i in 1:12){
   prod(i)
}
```

and also

```
for(i in 1:12){
   print(prod(i)
}
```

and also

```
for(i in 1:12){
   prod(i)
}
```

and also

```
for(i in 1:12){
   print(prod(i)
}
```

and also

many other code, and it does not work

Comment: What have you tried so far. Note this is not a platform to solve homeworks unless you could provide some efforts!

Comment: I spent 4 hours trying to figure how to do this problem with the textbook and the link that the instructor. They do not show how to do it. So I do not understand which part of the effort did I not put in it. I tried for(i in 1:12){ prod(i)} and many other different code that my brain could think of but it just doesn't work. I guess I have to put these code here to show I put in effort. BTW here is the link and textbook. Let me know if you see the section that teach upon this question. https://discdown.org/rprogramming/loops.html https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html?q=loop#looping-patterns

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and advice. I will not do the same mistake as before.

Answer (score 2):

**For**:

```
my_factorial<-function(x){
  y<-1
  for(i in 1:x) {
    y<-y*((1:x)[i])
  }
  return(y) 
}
my_factorial(12)
```

is the same as:

**`factorial`**

```
factorial(12)
```

OR
**You can use `gamma` for factorials:**

```
x = 12
gamma(x+1)
```

is the same as:

```
12*11*10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1
[1] 479001600
```

result:

```
[1] 479001600
```

Comment: Why `(1:x)[i]` instead of simply `i`, which is defined by `1:x`? 

Comment: @Martin Gal. I tried with `i` was not able to run it. ?!

Comment: I just tried it without any problems. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

If you want product of first numbers at each iteration

```
b=vector()
for (i in 1:12){
  b[i]=i
  print(prod(b))
}

[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 6
[1] 24
[1] 120
[1] 720
[1] 5040
[1] 40320
[1] 362880
[1] 3628800
[1] 39916800
[1] 479001600
```

This will be like

```
1
1*2
1*2*3
.
.
.
1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10*11*12
```

But if you want just the product of the 12 first positive integers then you do not need a `for` loop. just use product function.

```
prod(1:12)
[1] 479001600
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long time of critical thinking and studying other people's code,

I was able to finally create a more simple code that finds the factorials up to 12

```
b <- 1:12
```

This gives b a vector from 1 to 12

```
for(i in 1:1){
    print(prod(b))
}
```

this function tells r that:

for i, the variable of the sequence, in 1 line

please print the product of b

Answer:

```
[1] 479001600
```